# Css grid scalability

Tags: css, css-grid

I recently started working with css grid to create a layout for a website. I made a nice looking template for the home page. When I started developing the site and adding pages I quickly realized that I was going to need a grid for the content of each page. While this isn't a big deal for this project with only 3-4 pages, I can see this becoming hard to manage with larger websites that has different layouts for each page.

Tldr;
Using grid seems to force you into writing css for the content of each page rather than just using markup like in bootstrap. Can grid be used without having to write css for every page?

An example would be a website that has a layout for the home page content, one for a page with a form, one for a page to list articles, one for the articles themselves, etc. Already I have at least 5 different grids to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS Grid seems for me to be more maintainable and pure than Bootstrap table-like HTML structure (at least in most cases) because you are defining just elements in HTML and their layout in CSS.

Bootstrap is just predefined set of CSS classes, and you'd have to `<link>` it on every page. So what's the problem to create some common shared classes for CSS Grid layout if you have any repetitive parts and `<link>` everywhere you `<link>` like `bootstrap.css`?

Comment: That makes sense. So I can just define a generic grid class that I can reuse. Then define classes that I can use to position elements within each grid. My thought was to have classes for each column like col-start-n and col-end-n. To position an element would look something like <div class="col-start-3 col-end-6"></div> to have that element fill cells 3, 4, 5 and 6 of that row.